# How to implement an enumerator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.delete_if { |x| x > 3 }
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.delete_if.each.each.each.each { |x| x > 3 }
```

I know `a.delete_if` returns an enumerator. But how does it know it should delete object when the `each` block returns true? How to implement `delete_if` by hand(and in Ruby)?

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].delete_if.each.each.each.each { |x| x > 3 }` Could you please elaborate a bit more on this line?

Comment: why isn't `delete_if.each` the same as `each`? how does `delete_if` remember what should it do?

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at the Rubinius source code: [enumerable module](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerable.rb)

Here an example of the reject method:

```
  def reject
    return to_enum(:reject) unless block_given?

    ary = []
    each do |o|
      ary << o unless yield(o)
    end

    ary
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation of `delete_if`, the code can verify the value returned from `yield` to decide whether or not to delete the given entry from the array.

You can read [Implementing Iterators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html) in the Programming Ruby guide for more details, but it would looks something like:

```
class Array
  def delete_if
     reject { |i| yield i }.to_a
  end
end
```

The above uses `yield` to pass each item in the array to the block associated with the call to `delete_if`, and implicitly returns the value of the `yield` to the outer `reject` call.